# Is it possible to use the laws of termodynamics for non-ideal systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, kinetic-theory-of-gases

For the reaction

$$\ce{2CO(g) + O2(g) -> 2CO2(g)}\quad\Delta H = \pu{−560 kJ}$$

it is given that the reaction occurs at constant volume of $\pu{1L}$ and the initial and final pressures are $\pu{70 atm}$ and $\pu{40 atm},$ respectively, with an initial temperature of $\pu{500 K}.$ It is further given that all the gases show significant deviation from ideal behaviour.

I don't understand how we can apply the standard equation of

$$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta n_gRT \quad\text{or}\quad \Delta H = \Delta U +\Delta(PV)$$

As compared to

$$\Delta H = \Delta U + z\Delta n_gRT \quad\text{or}\quad \Delta H = \Delta U +\Delta(PV)/z$$

However, the only solutions I found to this problem use the standard equations.

Comment: Note that H = U + p.V by definition,no matter if the system is ideal or not. If we can neglect nonideality of a gas, we can use H = U + nRT

Comment: Yes, this can be done, at least up to moderate pressures like these if you know the 2nd virial coefficients for the pure gases.  You need to learn how to get the residual properties of gas mixtures at elevated pressures.  This is all explained in chapters 10-15 of Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and van Ness.  Do you at least know the mole fractions of the reactant and product mixtures?